# Swift compiler error: missing return in function

Tags: swift, xcode

Consider the following:

```
func test() -> Bool {
    for count in 0..<100 {
        return true 
    }
}
```

Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'. I do not see a case where the function will not return 'true', yet the code will not compile. Thoughts?

Comment: Usually you iterate the entire loop or you `return` on a condition or you `break` or `continue`, but a loop which returns immediately is completely pointless. The compiler never expects such a behavior. Instead it does expect a `return` value **after** the loop

Comment: Do you really expect it to return true 100 times? It will simply just return true on the first iteration, and as @vadian already mentioned you need to return a value after the loop. The compiler doesn't "know" that there is no chance of not returning a value.

Comment: It's an interesting edge case, but is completely covered by the duplicate.